# Cant change color in Gantry header for IE 8-9 (Joomla)

Tags: css, joomla, less

I'm working on a site http://www.solstack.se
It works great in all browsers but IE 8 and 9. In these the header background is a different color. light or dark grey depending on the setting in the gantry backend template. I need this to be transparent but I can't figure out how. I've  searched through all .less files for the correct code to modify, but with no luck. I guess it,s getting compiled somewhere. I also tried adding overrides in a *gantry-custom.css* file.

I need to get rid of these two lines from `#rt-top-surround`:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffdddddd', GradientType=0)

background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this in your index.php in your template folder:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <?php
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $css = '#rt-top-surround {background-color:none; filter:none; }';
        $doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);
    ?>
<![endif]-->
```

This basically says, if the browser being used is higher than or equal to IE8, then add the CSS code defined in the `$css` variable.

Hope this helps